# What is the word for when a person who is getting cancelled acts friendly to their audience?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Typically getting the public (negative) response of

> Oh look, now they are trying to _____

Not the word downplay or sugarcoat. But similar in meaning.

Comment: Can you be more precise? Are they apologising, saying nice things, distracting, trying to bribe, being conciliatory, saying they were misquoted...? A word for what they're doing or the effect it has? And do you want slang or formal language?

Comment: They are acting *Professionaly* which is to say, not childishly angry or petulant but in a dignified manner that may polish the reputation they have left. Usually in order to look good for the next job they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That activity could be described as **reputation laundering**, defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reputation_laundering) as follows:

> Reputation laundering occurs when a person or an organization conceals unethical, corrupt, or criminal behavior by performing highly-visible positive actions with the intent to improve their reputation and obscure their history.
>
> Reputation laundering can include gestures such as donating to charities, sponsoring sports teams, or joining prominent associations.